# Problems with Robotium signing using the android debug keystore

Tags: android, apk, robotium, jar-signing

I have access to the code for the app I am testing (myApp) and I have a suite of tests (myTest).  When I run my tests, Eclipse compiles and installs both myApp and myTest and all the tests run fine.  So far, so good.  Now I also want to be able to execute these tests against an apk of myApp, and I cannot get this to work due to signing issues.

As I understand it, the solution is to re-sign myApp.apk with the Android debug keystore's signature  so that myTest.apk and myApp.apk will have the same signature.  Renas' [Robotium tutorial](https://robotium.googlecode.com/files/AndroidCalculatorAPKTest.pdf) on the subject recommends a tool to do this, [re-sign.jar](http://www.troido.de/re-sign.jar).  This tool does seem to work, I can install and run the resulting apk file, but it doesn't wind up with the same signature as myTest.  In other words, when I run myTest (debug in eclipse, or from commandline) I get the error complaining that the test failed because myApp and myTest don't have the same signature.

I can work around this if I use re-sign.jar to re-sign both myApp.apk AND myTest.apk.  (although this is not a solution, since I cannot debug, only run the tests from the commandline.  Also, it's ugly.)  I don't understand why this should be - since myTest.apk was created automatically when I ran my test in eclipse, it should already have been signed with the debug keystore, and re-sign.jar should just reapply the same signature, right?

Maybe that tool is outdated or broken.  Well, Renas' tutorial also includes steps to re-sign the jar manually, like so:

```
jarsigner -keystore c:\androiddev\.android\debug.keystore 
    -storepass android -keypass android C:\blah\myApp.apk androiddebugkey
zipalign 4 C:\blah\myApp.apk C:\blah\myApp2.apk
```

This sems to work, and the afterwards, running "jarsigner -verify" returns "jar verified".  However, the resulting apk will not install:

```
C:\blah>adb install myApp.apk
    3739 KB/s (1922522 bytes in 0.502s)
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/myApp.apk
Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES]
```

Can anyone tell me what's going on here?  Stack has several other questions about "How do I use Robotium on an apk" and the answer is that tutorial I linked to earlier, but both methods of signing the apk listed in that tutorial fail for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused by having Java 7 installed and using instructions for Java 6.  I was able to sign the apk and install it after adding these params: -sigalg MD5withRSA -digestalg SHA1
Working commands:

```
jarsigner -keystore c:\androiddev\.android\debug.keystore 
    -storepass android -keypass android C:\blah\myApp.apk androiddebugkey
    -sigalg MD5withRSA -digestalg SHA1      
zipalign 4 C:\blah\myApp.apk C:\blah\myApp2.apk
```